# Error in Spring Boot - Error Creating Bean - No Property Found

Tags: spring-boot, properties, repository, javabeans, findall

In my Spring Boot Repository I have the following findAll's that work, except for the last findALL that uses the AND feature to select by two columns. The field names are valid as they work in the prior two lines, but when put together using the AND I get the following error:

Error creating bean with name 'siteReportCardDetailScoresController':.......

findAllBysitemasterIdANDsitereportcardmasterId(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long)! No property ANDsitereportcardmasterId found for type Long

**Any idea why? A solution to this mystery would be much appreciated.**

```
    @Repository
    public interface SiteReportCardDetailScoresRepository extends JpaRepository<SiteReportCardDetailScores, Long>{
    
        public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAll();
    
        public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAllBysitemasterId(Long sitemasterid);
    
        public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAllBysitereportcardmasterId(Long reportcardmasterid);
    
public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(Long sitemasterid,
            Long reportcardmasterid);
    
    }

//Controller
@GetMapping("/sitereportcarddetailscoresbysiteandreportcard/{sitemasterid, reportcardmasterid}")
    public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> getAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(@PathVariable Long sitemasterid, @PathVariable Long reportcardmasterid){
        return sitereportcarddetailscoresRepository.findAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(sitemasterid, reportcardmasterid);
    }
```

Comment: `AND` should be `And`.

Comment: I also had to capitalize the first letter of the search variables.  It compiles, but I get a status 404 Not Found when I am testing with Postman

`public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(Long sitemasterid,
   Long reportcardmasterid);
`
I added the controller code to the originaal post

Comment: OK..GetMapping was wrong syntax....here is correction:
 @GetMapping("/sitereportcarddetailscoresbysiteandreportcard/{sitemasterid}/{reportcardmasterid}")

Answer (score 0):

Case matters!... Correct Syntax for the repository and controller are as follows:
Repository

```
public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> findAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(Long sitemasterid,
            Long reportcardmasterid);
```

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/sitereportcarddetailscoresbysiteandreportcard/{sitemasterid}/{reportcardmasterid}")
    public List<SiteReportCardDetailScores> getAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(@PathVariable Long sitemasterid, @PathVariable Long reportcardmasterid){
        return sitereportcarddetailscoresRepository.findAllBySitemasterIdAndSitereportcardmasterId(sitemasterid, reportcardmasterid);
    }
```

@M. Deinum